# Trackpad behaviour - acting like mouse (OS X Macbook)

Tags: interface, customization, osx

Previously, using a trackpad with Blender on a Macbook was surprisingly easy and natural: Two-finger scrolling would smoothly rotate the view, pinching would zoom, and scrolling through controls was smooth also.

Recently, however, I have discovered that the trackpad seems to be acting like a mouse: scrolling zooms, multi-touch gestures aren't recognized, and scrolling scrolls in increments, like it does when using an old mouse-wheel.

Nosing around in the input preferences, I found that disabling the first two `Scroll Up` and `Scroll Down` controls under `View2D Buttons List` disables scrolling altogether, but content still moves from trackpad's inertia (without snapping to intervals, like desired). Also, disabling the last two `Zoom View` controls under `3D View > 3D View (Global)` does the same thing. I.e., two-finger swiping in the 3D view does nothing, but inertia from the gesture rotates the 3D view like desired.

How can I restore the old trackpad behavior? It seems like Blender is not realizing I am using a trackpad, but it is treating it like a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry—answered own question. Turns out to be related with the OS, not to do with Blender.

For any one else experiencing this problem, just sleep and wake the computer then relaunch Blender. Blender should now recognise trackpad input how it should. Hooray!